# Restrict access to TYPO3 backend via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ip, typo3, backend

I'm trying to restrict access to the TYPO3 backend **and** the install tool. Beacause of that, the IPMaskList isn't the best thing to do so. I tried an `.htaccess` file in the `/typo3` directory and it worked quite well to certain point. The following code was used to accomplish that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my_ip>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com [R=301]
```

Only the computer with the listed ip can access the `index.php` or `install.php`, which is very good. But as soon as I click the login button, and the URL changes to `https://example.com/typo3/login?loginProvider=1433416747`, it throws a 404 error. First, I thought it was the configured IP, as the server is requesting a page, and not my computer, but I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might just be that you are missing the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule`. The missing `L` flag will cause processing to continue through the remaining directives which probably includes a front-controller pattern. Typo3 then generates a 404 because `https://example.com` is not a valid "Typo3" URL.

---

But also...

> First, I thought it was the configured ip, as the server is requesting a page, and not my computer,

If the server itself is also making an HTTP request (although not sure why) then you will also need to permit the server's IP address in your rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my_ip>
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<server_ip>
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Additional changes:

- Missing `L` flag. (Mentioned above)
- Missing trailing slash after the hostname (the browser "corrects" it).
- No point capturing the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Although if you simply ant to restrict access then why not serve a "403 Forbidden" instead. Change the `RewriteRule` accordingly:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

(`L` flag not required here.)

---

**UPDATE:**

> No, by default there's no .htaccess in that dir, only the one in the root dir. Only with a .htaccess in the typo3 dir it's resulting in a 404. That's my only content in this particular .htaccess.

By enabling the rewrite engine in the subdirectory then it's going to completely override any mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file (by default), regardless of whether you are accessing the site by your IP or not. It would seem there are mod_rewrite directives in the parent/root `.htaccess` file that are required for your Typo3 installation to function (a front-controller pattern perhaps). (I had assumed these were all in the `/typo3/.htaccess` file.)

There are two solutions:

1. Move the above rule to the top of the root `.htaccess` file, adjusting accordingly. And delete the `/typo3/.htaccess` file. For example:

   ```
   # In the root ".htaccess" file
   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=<my_ip>
   RewriteRule ^typo3(/|$) - [F]
   ```

OR

2. Don't use mod_rewrite to block the request. For example, use an Apache expression with mod_authz_core instead. For example:

   ```
   # In the "/typo3/.htaccess" file
   <If "! -R '<my_ip>'">
       Require all denied
   </If>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue. One thing to note is, that TYPO3 is indeed trying to open a directory that doesn't exist, so the 404 error has it's reason (the login file or dir is not existent). But if I delete the .htaccess file and sign in normally, it's also accessing this dir/file, that is not exisiting. I propose, this is causing the issue.

Comment: @Kirneh What else do you have in the `.htaccess` file? "it's also accessing this dir/file, that is not exisiting." - But doesn't result in a 404?!

Comment: No, by default there's no .htaccess in that dir, only the one in the root dir. Only with a .htaccess in the typo3 dir it's resulting in a 404. That's my only content in this particular .htaccess.

Comment: @Kirneh Ah, if the root `.htaccess` file is required by the Typo3 installation then your rule in the subdirectory will "disable" the mod_rewrite directives in the parent. I've updated my answer. (The only way to know for sure is to see the contents of the root `.htaccess` file.)

Comment: @Kirneh Correction: The logic in the last expression was wrong - it needed to be negated! I've updated my answer.